# Javascript Filter Equation Explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get a better grasp of ES6 functions and filtering arrays. I came across this bit of code below and I'm at a loss. The first => starts the ES6 function if I'm not mistaken. So...function returns the length of s-a if it is less than or equal to d if d is less than or equal to t-a. Right?

```
array.filter(d => s - a <= d && d <= t - a).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions passed to the `filter` is the condition through which all items will be passed. And if the condition returns `true` for a item, it is pushed the result of the `filter` array. After it you are trying to get the length of the returned array. In your example each item is passed through the condition `s - a <= d && d <= t - a` and if the condition returns `true`, the item is pushed into the result. After all items checking, you get the length of the returned array accessing via `length` property.

Another example

Here I filter the array based on a condition - if the item is more than `5` - push into the result, otherwise skip it. After all I get the length of the `filteredArray` (how many items are in the result array - which have passed the condition).

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const filteredArray = numbers.filter(eachNumber => eachNumber > 5);

console.log(filteredArray.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was very helpful!